# MSDN subscription appears only limited to Visual Studio

Tags: windows-10, msdn

The one thing I keep hearing over and over again is - why don't you get an actual licensed subscription and download a windows edition from msdn directly and legitimately -

So I thought I would follow this through and try to find how to acquire an MSDN subscription to download windows 10 Pro or Enterprise. I had a lot of difficulty actually finding out how to do this -- the only thing I ever got to was getting a subscription for visual studio...

I can't even find where I would go to pay microsoft for an edition of enterprise, I can only find an evaluation version of it.

So where do I go if I wanted to purchase a MSDN subscription that permits me to download windows editions, or even some sliding tier of more or less editions to download.

I must be missing something, because people seem to make it sound easy...

Comment: [Visual Studio Pricing](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/pricing/) shows you which subscriptions include Windows. [Software for dev/test](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/5/4/15454442-CF17-47B9-A65D-DF84EF88511B/Visual_Studio_by_Subscription_Level.xlsx) shows the complete list of software included for each subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in subscribing you should call the sales department and describe what you want. Since the number is likely localized I won’t provide the number.

MSDN licenses have always been restricted to software development hence the reason it was called Microsoft Developer Network

> MSDN subscriptions are now called Visual Studio subscriptions, but even with a new name you still get the same great value to support your development on any platform—current and past versions of Visual Studio and other Microsoft software for dev/test, use of Visual Studio Team Services, developer training, support, and much more!

[Source](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/pricing/)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I didn’t do a very good job cropping the table but it’s “good enough”, my advice of **calling** the sales department, is a very good suggestion

Comment: I see where they hid that on your link. I never was even able to find that pricing guide! It lists MSDN OS in the xlsx though...yet only two options on the web page...not sure if MSDN OS is not offered anymore or something.

Comment: What is the last of the images for?

Comment: Well the table is 10+ columns wide I can only fit 5 on my screen.

Answer (score 1):

You would go to the Visual Studio website, and choose one of their products with subscriber benefits.

For example, the Visual Studio Professional subscription, which comes with Subscriber Benefits. These benefits then include Windows and other tools. Be aware, there might restrictions on those Windows Licenses, such as only to be used for testing.

I don't think these licenses are sold separate. See [visualstudio.com](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/pricing/) for more information.

Comment: MSDN portal has been decommissioned so all MSDN subscriptions are handled through Visual Studio

Comment: I see - so it really it is a thing that had changed and made previous comments outdated. Everything goes through visual studio then.

Comment: Considering MSDN was always targeted to developers it’s not shocking they combined MSDN into the new Visual Studio website.